# How to reference a user's login in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, authentication, oracle-apex

I'm trying to automatically display my user's login information on a merchant request page in a text field named P_Username. UI and the code behind merchant request shown below

[Merchant Request UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmByZ.png)
[Merchant Request Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAHG2.png)

I assumed I would just set the source of P_Username to the text field that I entered my username into upon login (P9999_USERNAME). UI and the code behind login page shown below

[Login UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvvE6.png)
[Login Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIvJt.png)

The login page was automatically created in my apex application so I did not create the table in which that login information was saved under. I'm fairly new to stack overflow, so feel free to give me any tips on how to better ask/portray my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Username you're looking for (e.g. "collin", as displayed on the 1st screenshot) is - in Apex - `:APP_USER`. Literally like that; a colon `:` followed by `APP_USER`.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a reason the value had to be called through PL/SQL?

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately, I don't understand what you mean by saying that. Which PL/SQL?

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm not sure why I had to select the source type of "PL/SQL Expression". If it's just a value stored in the db, why wouldn't I just be using type SQL Query (Return single value) and then something like "Select :APP_USER From SOME_TABLE"

Comment: Sorry, missed the comment you posted. You can - theoretically - do that (select from some_table), but that "some_table" **must** contain only one row; otherwise you'll get NO_DATA_FOUND (if table is empty) or TOO_MANY_ROWS (if table contains more than a single row) error.